# MS Outlook 2016 cannot search

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, microsoft-outlook-2016, search-indexing

Lately, it seems everyone will have this happen to them at my company.

They are unable to search in Outlook past a certain date. I've verified when the errors start in the Event Viewer corresponding to when their search broke.

The error is this:
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Search
Date:          5/22/2017 8:34:13 PM
Event ID:      3083
Task Category: Gatherer
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      POWPC17021702.domain.com
Description:
The protocol handler OneIndex16 cannot be loaded. Error description: (HRESULT : 0x800700c1).

Event Xml:

  
    
    3083
    0
    2
    3
    0
    0x80000000000000
    
    11512
    
    
    Application
    POWPC17021702.hme.com
    
  
  
    
    
    OneIndex16
    (HRESULT : 0x800700c1)
  
 
The protocol handler OneIndex16 cannot be loaded. Error description: (HRESULT : 0x800700c1).

And also:

Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Search
Date:          5/23/2017 12:31:45 AM
Event ID:      3083
Task Category: Gatherer
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      POWPC17021702.hme.com
Description:
The protocol handler Mapi16 cannot be loaded. Error description: (HRESULT : 0x80004005).

Event Xml:

  
    
    3083
    0
    2
    3
    0
    0x80000000000000
    
    11524
    
    
    Application
    POWPC17021702.hme.com
    
  
  
    
    
    Mapi16
    (HRESULT : 0x80004005)

I have looked through numerous systems on my network and am not able to find a trace leading up to these Search errors. They just sort of happen.

Every system as reported a different set of logs leading up to the Search Errors. Mind you, these errors show up in Event Viewer about every 15 minutes from the moment they first appear.

I've done the rebuilding off the index, recreating Outlook profiles, updating Office to the latest build, taking Outlook of the deferred scheduled updates to current, and I've tried disabling indexing for Outlook -- it allows them to search from the exchange server - but it is very slow and definitely not as quick as it was before and will not work for remote users.

The only "solution" I have found that seems to work is recreating the Windows Profile and copying all their data/files back over. It is a time consuming task and since it is affecting most people in my company (through reasons I have still yet to find), I was wondering if anyone has found an actual working solution to this problem. Or even if anyone has experienced a company-wide Outlook searching issue.

Any help would be very much appreciated! Apparently this has been going on for months for some users at the company and only just started to report it a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_win10/outlook-2016-search-fails-the-protocol-handler/9b49590c-0858-4934-b358-7af0469fe313 They probably fixed this in one of the later builds. Check if true.

Answer (score 0):

you may compare the following registry keys on the normal clients and affected clients:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/csstwplatform/2010/07/29/desktop-search-event-3083-window-search-mapi2handler-1-cannot-be-loaded/

Besides, I would suggest you check if this issue began to happen after any Office updates were installed, or if the affected clients is the same version as the normal ones.